# Using variable in vue data object for nested loop calculation causes code to break

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

So i have an object that i want to use in performing some calculations on the sub-objects which it contains before rendering inside a span tag like so:

`<span>getTotal(costing_day)</span>`

`getTotal` is a method that does the following:

```
costing_days.forEach((day) =>{
          day.project_material.forEach((material) => {
             this.total += (parseInt(material.amount) * parseInt(material.quantity));
          });

          day.project_labour.forEach((labour) => {
             this.total += (parseInt(labour.amount) * parseInt(labour.quantity));
          });
          return this.total
      });
```

And it makes use of the `total` property declared in my vue data object.
But it squawks saying i have an infinite loop in my component,

Now i used a local `total` variable in the function performing this loop's calculation like so:

```
      let total = 0
      costing_days.forEach((day) =>{

          day.project_material.forEach((material) => {
             total += (parseInt(material.amount) * parseInt(material.quantity));
          });

          day.project_labour.forEach((labour) => {
             total += (parseInt(labour.amount) * parseInt(labour.quantity));
          });  
      });

      return total;
```

And it works fine.
Can anyone help me understand why the local variable works while the one in the data object throws an error?

Comment: Where is it happening? In a watcher, computed or method?

Comment: Its happening in a method

Comment: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/item-total-item-total-infinite-loop/1318
Some weird behaviour by vuejs

Comment: My guess is that your template calls the method, which in turn updates the `total`, which in turn triggers a re-rendering, which in turn calls the method and so on.

Comment: @Willower have you used total in computed as well?

Comment: @aefxx yes, it should go through the loop you outlined quite alright, but that doesn't necessarily make the loop infinite.

Comment: If the rendering calls the method, and the method in turn triggers a re-rendering, then that's what I would call an infinite loop, or not?

Comment: @Helpinghand i'm reading the link you shared now, and i will try it in computed too.
But still that's besides the point as i've got it to work already as a local variable don't you think?.
I just want to understand why it works for other ways but not in the data object

Comment: Because Vue registers any access to bound (reactive) `data` properties and will want to update the component if you're triggering the properties `setter`.

Comment: @aefxx i see your point... please explain this... why would updating total cause a re-rendering? 
See how i called the method 
`<span>getTotal(costingWeek.costing_day)</span>`

Comment: @aefxx Ohhh i just saw you last comment. Makes better sense now.
Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, Willower, you will need to properly update your question for us to be more helpful.

Comment: @aefxx Okay i will add how i called the method in the question for better clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue's reactivity is handled with getter's and setter's, and each change to a set variable immediately fires a re-render.

As suggested in the comments by @aefxx - every time you update `this.total` it tries to re-render the template, which in turn fires off your method again - causing the infinite loop.

This is why using a local variable fixed it - `this.total` is never set - all you're doing is returning a value, and vue renders it.

More info on vue reactivity:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html